# How to Call CMD.EXE from PowerShell with a Space in the Specified Command's Directory Name

Tags: svn, powershell, cmd, visualsvn-server

I have the following PowerShell script for verifying my SVN repositories:

```
$SVNAdminDir = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin';
$RepositoryDir = 'C:\My Repositories\App1';
$_cmd = "`"$SVNAdminDir`\svnadmin`" verify `"$RepositoryDir`"";
Write-Host $_cmd; # Copying this into the command prompt runs without an issue...
cmd.exe /c $_cmd; # It's when I try to execute the command from PS that I get the error.
```

But when I try to execute it, I'm receiving the following error message:

```
cmd.exe : 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
At line:5 char:12
+     cmd.exe <<<<  /c $_cmd;
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ('C:\Program' is...ternal command,:String) [],     RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

operable program or batch file.
```

Since I'm essentially setting `$cmd = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin" verify "C:\My Repositories\App1"';` with the double quotes inside of the single quotes, I was expecting the space in **C:\Program Files (x86)\...** to be passed correctly.

I suspect there's something trivial with the string that I'm missing...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to call `cmd.exe` like this:

```
cmd.exe /c "`"$_cmd`""
```

The commands you send to `cmd.exe` need to be entirely wrapped in their own quotes, not just the paths-with-spaces that are part of those commands. This has to do with how Powershell parses the string and it needs to pass literal quotes to `cmd.exe` so that it in turn does its own parsing of the contents of double-quotes correctly.

For example, if you were already in a `cmd.exe` session and set a variable like this:

```
C:\>set _cmd="C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\bin\svnadmin" verify "C:\My Repositories\App1"
```

Then simply expanding that variable at the commandline would work:

```
C:\>%_cmd%
```

However, if passing it to a new `cmd.exe` session, it would also need extra quotes:

```
C:\>cmd.exe /c "%_cmd%"
```

Comment: I've not been able to get this to work in PowerShell. `cmd.exe` continually errors out complaining that `'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command...`.  I'm running PowerShell 5.1.  Any ideas?

Comment: so the powershell escape character is backtick?