# Powershell CMD.exe and spaces in path

Tags: powershell

I am running into a problem executing a command using `cmd.exe` in PowerShell. The problem is the path to the command has spaces in it. Seems to be a general problem with PowerShell.
Below is an extract:

```
$base_dir = resolve-path ..\  # this path has spaces in it 
$msdeploy = $base_dir\tools\msdeploy\msdeploy.exe

cmd.exe /c $("""$msdeploy"" -verb:sync -source:....")
```

I need to have the path to `msdeploy` resolve through variables as the script is used in a continuous integration process.

The command wont execute due to the spaces. I have tried to wrap the command in `""` (quotes) but still no luck. How do I format the `$msdeploy` variable in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling everything with the $() like this:

```
$base_dir = resolve-path ..\  # this path has spaces in it 
$msdeploy = $($base_dir)\tools\msdeploy\msdeploy.exe

cmd.exe /c $("$($msdeploy) -verb:sync -source:....")
```

Edit:  I moved the whole command into the $msdeploy variable, and called the $msdeploy by escaping the quotes.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471320/how-to-call-cmd-exe-from-powershell-with-a-space-in-the-specified-commands-dire) link that had a similar problem, so I adjusted your code to match what worked there.

```
$base_dir = resolve-path ..\
$msdeploy = $("`"" + $base_dir.Path + "\tools\msdeploy\msdeploy.exe`" -verb:sync -source:....")

cmd.exe /c "`"$msdeploy`""
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work. the single ' act as a literal and does not let the $($msdeploy) variable unpack

Comment: Try changing the $msdeploy to what I have up there.  Also, change the single `'` to `"`

Comment: Bro, saved me hours! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Nick have you used Psake at all?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I am still new to PowerShell, I just happened to have done this exact same thing in my first script, so it was fresh in my head when I read your question.

Answer (score 2):

Back-ticking "" around the command should make it work:

```
cmd.exe /c "`"$msdeploy`" -verb:sync -source:..."
```

Comment: That _is_ strange. I tried myself setting it up just like you, with the difference that `$msdeploy` was set up with quotes: `$msdeploy = "$base_dir\..."` (to ensure it's a string, just old habit). And I could call `cmd.exe /c "`"$msdeploy`" -help -verb"` without problems.