# Execute batch file with spaces in path

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have problems to execute a batch file on a remote server via PowerShell. The user can choose several opinions in a pop-up window like *Servername*, *starting* or *killing* process and *Servicename*. The chosen items will be saved in variables.

If all items are chosen, I want to merge the strings to one string and execute the batch script which is named like this result string.
I try to do it as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846087/powershell-cmd-exe-and-spaces-in-path/33215731#33215731), but the batch script won't be executed.

Example:

```
[String]$scriptpath="C:\tmp\"
[String]$Servername = "xx040"
[String]$actionprefix = "kill_process"
[String]$action = $($actionprefix) + "-"
[String]$Servicename = "service1"
[String]$ServiceFullname = $($action) + $($Servicename) + ".bat"
$batchPath = $("`"$scriptpath + $ServiceFullname `"")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servername -ScriptBlock {
  cmd.exe /c "`"$batchPath`""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not passing in anything to your invoke-command, so when it's running remotely it doesn't know what `$batchPath` is.  Take a look at this SO answer [How do I pass named parameters with Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servername -ScriptBlock {param($batchPath) cmd.exe /c "`"$batchPath`"" } -ArgumentList $batchPath
```

Is how you would want to make your call.

Comment: You're right! Now the batch script is running successfully. I'd found a mistake in my code: Changed $batchPath = $("`"$scriptpath + $ServiceFullname `"") to $batchPath = $("`"$scriptpath\$ServiceFullname `"")

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the [call operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx#The_Call_Operator_amp) (`&`) and put the variable with the path to your batch file in double quotes.

```
& "$batchPath"
```

You also need to make the variable `$batchPath` known inside your scriptblock via the `using:` scope modifier, otherwise `$batchPath` inside the scriptblock would be a different (empty) variable than `$batchPath` outside the scriptblock.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Servername -ScriptBlock {
  & "$using:batchPath"
}
```

An alternative would be to pass the variable into the scriptblock as an argument:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer $Servername -ScriptBlock {
  Param($BatchPath)
  & "$BatchPath"
} -ArgumentList $batchPath
```

Use [`Join-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) for building paths, so you don't need to deal with leading/trailing path separators yourself. Also, PowerShell expands variables in double-quoted strings, allowing you to avoid excess concatenations. In single-quoted strings variables are not expanded, so I normally use double quotes for strings with, and single quotes for strings without variables in them.

Modified code:

```
$Servername   = 'xx040'
$scriptpath   = 'C:\tmp'
$actionprefix = 'kill_process'
$Servicename  = 'service1'

$batchPath = Join-Path $scriptpath "$actionprefix-$Servicename.bat"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Servername -ScriptBlock {
   & "$using:batchPath"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to avoid paths with spaces in them is to use the 8.3 short notation.

Open a command line in Windows and use the `/x` parameter of dir. To find the shortname of the program files dir you would use `dir C:\prog* /x`. This is the result:

```
21.10.2015  14:46    <DIR>          PROGRA~1     Program Files
21.10.2015  12:47    <DIR>          PROGRA~2     Program Files (x86)
04.09.2014  18:25    <DIR>          PR6AFF~1     Programs16Bit
```

If you were to address `C:\Program Files` you could write `C:\PROGRA~1` too.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea as creating `8dot3` NTFS filenames could be disabled (per volume or even per system). See `fsutil.exe behavior set Disable8dot3 /?` and [Disable short file name creation](http://www.itnotes.eu/?p=2322). Some admins do this because they believe that [disabling 8.3 file name creation increases file performance under Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/121007), so for _performance reasons_ they disable it on their file servers.

Comment: @JosefZ I would say "it depends" ;-) We can only hope that never one of those "bored administrators" sets `DisableCMD=1` (see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787344(v=ws.10).aspx).